# printing client ip when server is on same machine

Tags: c, sockets, tcp

I am writing a simple tcp echo client server code both my client and server code are running on the same machine i did bind two different addresses to client and server but client ip address is not getting printed when connected to server i changed addresses and still i was not able to print address i don't see any mistake in code.Is this my os issue or am i making some mistake.

my server code:

```
    #include<stdio.h>
    #include<stdlib.h>
    #include<sys/socket.h>
    #include<sys/types.h>
    #include<string.h>
    #include<netinet/in.h>

    #define ERROR -1
    #define MAX_CLIENTS 10
    #define MAX_DATA 1024

    int main(int argc, char *argv[]){

        struct sockaddr_in server;
        struct sockaddr_in client;

        int sock;
        int new;
        int sockaddr_len = sizeof(struct sockaddr_in);
        int data_len;
        char data[MAX_DATA+1];

        if((sock = socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,0)) == ERROR){

            perror("server socket");
            exit(-1);

        }

        server.sin_family = AF_INET;
        server.sin_port = htons(atoi(argv[1]));
        inet_aton(argv[2],&server.sin_addr.s_addr);
        bzero(&server.sin_zero,0);

        if(bind(sock, (struct sockaddr *)&server,sockaddr_len) == ERROR){

            perror("bind");
            exit(-1);
        }

        if(listen(sock, MAX_CLIENTS) == ERROR){

            perror("listen");
            exit(-1);
        }

        while(1){

            if((new = accept(sock,(struct sockaddr *)&client,&sockaddr_len)) == ERROR){ 

                perror("accept");
                exit(-1);

            }

    //ip not getting printed
            printf("New client connected from port no %d IP %s\n",ntohs(client.sin_port),inet_ntoa(client.sin_addr.s_addr));

    data_len = 1;

    while(data_len){

        data_len = recv(new,data,MAX_DATA,0);

        if(data_len){

            send(new, data, data_len,0);
            data[data_len] = '\0';
            printf("Sent message: %s", data);


        }

    }

    printf("Client disconnected\n");
    close(new);

}
    }
```

my client code:

```
    #include<stdio.h>
    #include<stdlib.h>
    #include<sys/socket.h>
    #include<sys/types.h>
    #include<string.h>
    #include<netinet/in.h>

    #define ERROR -1
    #define BUFFER 1024

    int main(int argc, char *argv[]){

        struct sockaddr_in remote_server,client;
        int sock,len;

        char input[BUFFER];
        char output[BUFFER+1];


        client.sin_family = AF_INET;
        client.sin_port = htons(3000);
        inet_aton("127.0.2.8",&client.sin_addr.s_addr);
        bzero(&client.sin_zero,0);

        if((sock = socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,0)) == ERROR){
            perror("socket");
            exit(-1);
        }

        int size = sizeof(struct sockaddr_in);

        if(bind(sock, (struct sockaddr *)&client,size) == ERROR){

            perror("bind");
            exit(-1);
        }

        remote_server.sin_family = AF_INET;
        remote_server.sin_port = htons(atoi(argv[2]));
        remote_server.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(argv[1]); 
        bzero(&remote_server.sin_zero , 0);

        if((connect(sock ,(struct sockaddr *)&remote_server , sizeof(struct sockaddr_in))) == ERROR){

            perror("connect");
            exit(-1);

        }

while(1){

    fgets(input, BUFFER, stdin);
    send(sock, input, strlen(input) , 0);

    len = recv(sock,output,BUFFER,0);

    output[len] = '\0';

    printf("%s\n",output);

}

close(sock);

 }
```

This is the output:
New client connected from port no 3000 and IP

Comment: You can use `getpeername()` on the accepted socket as an alternative.

Comment: Is port getting printed correctly?

Comment: Probably you should use _client.sin_addr_ and not _client.sin_addr.s_addr_ inside inet_ntoa()

Comment: yes port is getting printed correctly

Comment: no sin_addr is not printing

Comment: this is the output  "New client connected from port no 3000 and IP"

Comment: Code worked for me. `New client connected from port no 3000 IP 192.168.56.101`

Comment: are you running both codes in same machine on different terminals and by the way the ip i binded to it was different than your output

Comment: I am running in the same host. I edited the client code to bind to IP that my host binds

Comment: is it not running with the existing proxy

Comment: I've tried running with `client.sin_addr` instead of `client.sin_addr.s_addr` inside inet_ntoa() and inet_aton(). Its running perfectly fine and printing the IP.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need **two more includes** in client as well as server

```
#include<arpa/inet.h> // for inet_aton(), inet_addr() and inet_ntoa()
#include<unistd.h> //for close()
```

Secondly,

The function declaration for inet_aton() and inet_ntoa() are respectively:

```
int inet_aton(const char *cp, struct in_addr *inp);
```

and

```
char *inet_ntoa(struct in_addr in);
```

So, You must pass the entire structure i.e `xyzaddr.sin_addr` instead of `xyzaddr.sin_addr.s_addr`(which is an int)

Hence **make these changes as well**:

**In server:**

`inet_aton(argv[2],&server.sin_addr.s_addr);` -> `inet_aton(argv[2],&server.sin_addr);`

`inet_ntoa(client.sin_addr.s_addr)` -> `inet_ntoa(client.sin_addr)`

**In client:**

`inet_aton("127.0.2.8",&client.sin_addr.s_addr);` -> `inet_aton("127.0.2.8",&client.sin_addr);`